# How to sum a column that is based on an expression in SSRS ReportBuilder table

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

If have a column where the value is based on another field, so the expression is

```
=iif(Fields!TaskType.Value = "Type1", Fields!Amount.Value, 0)
```

And I'm trying to get the sum of this in the group totals using the folooing exporession, but it gives #Error (with or without the group name as scope):

```
=sum(iif(Fields!TaskType.Value="Type1", Fields!Amount.Value, 0), "GrpProjectNumber")
```

This looks fine to me. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the specific error message? I created a dummy DataSet with the same names as yours and tested your conditional sum expression; it worked fine.

Comment: Where do I see the error message? All I see is the text #Error in the table cell...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure in Report Builder - there is some logging of runtime processing errors in the Report Server log file but it's pretty terse. OK, another question... What is the underlying data type of `Fields!Amount.Value`?

Comment: It's actually a varchar field cast as money in a view.  I tried casting the field in the expression to cdec(Fields!Amount.Value) but no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've constructed a simple DataSet to try and mimic yours:

```
select Amount = cast(100.0 as money), TaskType = 'Type1'
  union all select Amount = cast(100.0 as money), TaskType = 'Type1'
  union all select Amount = cast(100.0 as money), TaskType = 'Type2'
```

I replicated your error with your expression, but the following works for me:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!TaskType.Value="Type1", Fields!Amount.Value, CDec(0)), "GrpProjectNumber")
```

So it seems like you were on the right path; just needed to apply the `CDec` cast to the `0` constant in the expression.

Comment: Ha, so simple, eh!  I can stop beating my head on the desk now. Many thanks!